# Creating email alert workflow for SharePoint file libraries

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I cannot use the alerts function on the SharePoint due to how the SharePoint permissions is updated in our system. I would change this if I could but I would have to completely redo SharePoint setup.

On to my question though.

A user wants me to make a workflow to send out an email alert when a document is uploaded or changed in SharePoint. I have searched for something that would do this but I have had no luck so far. I would appreciate any help.

I am attempting to make this workflow in SharePoint designer 2010 for a SharePoint 2010 site.

UPDATE:

I have found the libraries that are not working have sub folders or have Create Major Versions activated in versioning settings. I am not sure why this breaks the email alerts but any advice would be appreciated.

UPDATE 2:

The only libraries that are having issues now are the libraries with Create Major Versions activated in versioning settings.

I found the libraries with sub folders worked but the original libraries I was testing the three that were breaking 2 had no folders inside and the other did so I thought it might be an issue. I was incorrect so have eliminated that option.

Comment: Out of interest - how is it setup that stops alerts working?

Comment: I have found that the libraries that I cannot get to send the workflow have either sub folders the workflow does not look inside, or in versioning setting the Create Major Versions is turned on. I am not sure why that would break it but this is the only difference I could find in the lists.

Comment: Thats why the Workflow isn't working for you right? - but what about the OOTB alerts - why can't you use them?

Comment: Our SharePoint permissions are all deleted overnight and are then re added. I took over support of this so was not the one who set that up so I really don't know why the person who set it up did that but it makes alerts useless as if your permissions are deleted all alerts associated with you are deleted as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Sharepoint Designer select the library you want to add the workflow to.

1. Click on "List Worklfow" on the ribbon
2. Provide a Name for your workflow and an optional Description
3. In the workflow designer setup your workflow:

   a. Add Action "send email"

   b. Specify the email parameters you can use Lookups to search for values related to the item you have uploaded or modified. For instance in the field to you can select a Sharepoint Group or even the user who created the current item

   c. In the body field you can insert values like Document Name, Title etc by clicking on add or change lookup

   d. Add more actions as needed
4. Click on Workflow Settings in the Ribbon
5. Untick Allow this workflow to be started manually and enable on created and is changed.
6. Save the workflow by clicking the save button in the ribbon
7. Publish the workflow by clicking the publish button in the ribbon

Workflow should now be activated for that Library.

Comment: I have found that some of the libraries have folders inside and the workflow does not look inside them. I have looked through the available actions but did not see anything. Is there a way to make it look inside the folders? Also some of the libraries will not send an email out. The only thing I have noticed that is different about these is they have Create Major Versions checked in Versioning Settings.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, I've had no issues with a workflow not working correctly whether the document went into a subfolder or if versioning was turned on. I would check to make sure that if Versioning is turned on, check the Content Approval, Draft Item Security, and Require Check out settings to see if that may cause an issue. Also, check the workflow activity reports as it may provide why it is failing. You may also need to check and see if the workflow is set to run on a specific content type. Lastly, I would try to find any documentation as to why the previous person that created the permissions workflow to determine the affect it would have if it was removed as it appears to be more of a hinderance than helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I would share what I discovered.

I was having the same issue in that the alerts would not get sent out when a document is uploaded. I ended up doing the following and it seems to work so far.

1. When a document is uploaded there is 1 required field (mine is department) this required field ensures that the workflow doesn't get started until this is completed
2. I have the following conditions set up within my Sp

If Current Item: Content Type ID equals Document (I got this from someone here I am sorry I forget who)

and

Current item:Department equals Human Resources (or whatever you want it to be)

Email: Users

I noticed that when I uploaded the document the workflow showed complete and it is however you haven't put the parameters in to kick off the alert and it says "This document doesn't need to get sent off because it is not an Human Resources document."

You can also make this work by uploading the document and then editing the parameters. If the Workflow settings is set to kick off when a document is updated this will also trigger the alerts.